# Assign random values in a pandas column proportionately by group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

df dataframe like this:

```
ID   Category   Result
1     A          ...
2     B          ...
3     B          ...
4     C          ...
```

Wherever the category is A, in them, assign three values of result(Pass,Fail,Hold) in random order given the proportion being 30,40,30 for each Result type.
Similarly for other categories with different proportions.
Any fast way to do this?

Currently I am using

```
np.split(df[cond],int([.3*len(df[cond])]),int([.7*len(df[cond])]))
```

to split the data into proportions followed by

```
df1[Result] = 'Pass'
df2[Result] = 'Fail'...
pd.concat([df1,df2,...all conditioned columns frames])
```

to get the full set.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea. You can use `GroupBy` with `np.random.choice`.

This doesn't guarantee your proportions are kept. For example, if you only have one row for a specific category, it cannot guarantee your proportions are kept if your weights are all non-zero. Even if they *can* be kept, the logic still uses "random" numbers to select each value. What you *can* say, with this method, is as your number of rows tends towards infinity, the ratios will tend towards the provided weights.

```
values = ['Pass', 'Fail', 'Hold']
weights = {'A': [0.3, 0.4, 0.3], 'B': [0.6, 0.2, 0.2]}

df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': list('A'*10 + 'B'*5)})

np.random.seed(0)

def apply_randoms(x):
    key = x['Category'].iat[0]
    return pd.Series(np.random.choice(values, size=len(x), p=weights[key]))

df = df.groupby('Category').apply(apply_randoms)\
       .rename('Result').reset_index().drop('level_1', 1)

print(df)

   Category Result
0         A   Hold
1         A   Fail
2         A   Fail
3         A   Hold
4         A   Pass
5         A   Pass
6         A   Pass
7         A   Hold
8         A   Hold
9         A   Hold
10        B   Hold
11        B   Fail
12        B   Pass
13        B   Fail
14        B   Pass
```